# Admob is not working in flutter latest version 3.03. App Crashes after adding admob sdk

Tags: flutter, admob

I have tried googl_mobile_ads and admob_flutter. Both SDK Crashes App. Is there someone facing the same issue

Comment: Any logs / stacktrace?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your application id to the `AndroidMainfest.xml` ?

```xml
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
  android:value="ca-app-pub-..."/>
```

Follow this official tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter/